# Include Object and Object's Foreign Keys in One Query Django

Tags: python, django

I have the following models:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True) 
    reference = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
         return self.Name

class Subdocument(models.Model)
    document = models.ForeignKey(Document, null=True, default=None)
    pdf = models.FileField(upload_to='media')
```

Ultimately I want to show both the `name` from Document and the `pdf` from Subdocument in the same `<li>` in my template within a for loop.  So it could be something like:

```
{% for item in something %}
      <li class="list-group-item">
        {{ item.Name }} {{ item.pdf }}
      </li>
{% endfor %}
```

My issue is because they are in separate models, I'm not sure how to get fields from both. So what query, or queries could I run in my view in order to make this possible?  Any other approach is welcome, this is just to illustrate my end goal.

Thank you!

EDIT:

## views.py

```
def doc_view(request):
    something = Subdocument.objects.filter(document__isnull=False)
    return render(request, 'my_template.html', context={'something': something})
```

Comment: show me your views.py so that we can solve

Comment: I've added my view to the question although it is same as answer below which does not seem to be working.

Comment: def __str__(self):
         return self.Name   N should be small

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this,

```
# views.py
def my_view(request):
    docs = Subdocument.objects.filter(document__isnull=False)  # filtering out empty documents
    return render(request, 'my_template.html', context={'docs': docs})

# my_template.html
{% for doc in docs %}
      <li class="list-group-item">
        {{ doc.document.name }} {{ doc.pdf.url }}
      </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: yes actually this is exactly what I am trying...but it seems ```{{ doc.document.name }}``` renders nothing to the template. sorry should've included my view initially.

Comment: 1. it should be `doc.document.name` not `item.Name` 2. if this doesn't display the `name`, it indicates your DB missing those values

Comment: yes I've corrected what you mentioned in 1, but the name still does not display and checking the admin, there is indeed data in the Name field. But interestingly it does create a ```<li>```

Comment: try `{{ doc.document.id }}` instead of `{{ doc.document.name }}` and check the output. Is there anything displayed?

Comment: no...still blank even in that case. hmm is there some issue with my model then?

Comment: did the URL display?

Comment: ahh there I got it - it was actually just a typo on my part! awesome working now.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

models.py
replace

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
```

to

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=False)
```

template

```
{% for item in something %}
      <li class="list-group-item">
        {{ item.document.name }} {{ item.pdf }}
      </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: how does your answer differ from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60879436/12578202) ?